# How to plot bars over a scale at desired positions

Tags: r, plot, scale, genetics

I am trying to plot visualisation of a chromosome joining event. I want to be able to plug in the coordinates of a chromosome and get a bar above the scale corresponding to those coordinates. So essentially, like in this picture:

[image]

And I want to join the different bars that I get plotted with dashed lines for further visualisation. How is it possible to do this visualisation in R?

I have found a few packages for genomic visualisation, but I need something much simpler, just for drawing the bars and then customising things myself.